# AdMob Ads on exit

Tags: android, cordova, admob

I am creating an app with phonegap and using admob i am displaying fullpage ads on exit.

Is it ok to do so?

I am not blocking the user to exit the app
i am doing it like this

```
function backCall(e){
// pormt when back button is pressed on home screen
  e.preventDefault();
  var action=confirm("Do you want to Exit");
  if(action){
      if(AdMob) AdMob.showInterstitial();
      navigator.app.exitApp();
  }
```

So if the admob object is available the ad will show and the app will exit but if the admob object is not available then the app will exit anyway

I did not find anything the documentation.
Please let me know if i missed something in the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't put ads on **app load or exit** according to Google guidelines.
Please read [here](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201362?hl=en&ref_topic=2745287).